# c# помогите с классами

Tags: c#, классы

```
public class Element
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Hp { get; set; }

    }    
// класс элемента


public class Recept 
        {
            private Element[,] recept;
            int size;

            public Recept(Element elementZero, Element elementOne, Element elementTwo, Element elementThee, Element elementFour, Element elementFive, Element elementSix, Element elementSeven, Element elementEight)
            {
                size = 3;

                recept = new Element [,]{ { elementZero, elementOne, elementTwo}, { elementThee ,  elementFour, elementFive}, { elementSix, elementSeven, elementEight} };
            }

        }
    // рецепты для создание нового элемента из сочетаний элементов и их позиции


           Recept stick = new Recept(null, null, null, null, tree, null, null, tree, null);
// для примера сделал рецепт палки


    // здесь создаю массив рецептов чтобы после смерить с  details  все ли элементы есть и позиция ровняется ли как на рецепте
        private Recept[, ,] receptArray;
           size = 3;
           private int size;
           int count;
           count = 21;
           details = new Element[size, size];
           receptArray = new Recept[count, size, size];

    //как сравнить значение с recept и receptArray ?

    //пытаюсь обратится через индексы
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {                
                        for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
                        {
                            for (int l = 0; l < size; l++)
                            {
                                // Element templaye = new Element { Name = receptArray[i, k].Name }; пытался так не получилось 
                                if (receptArray[i, k, l] == details[k,l)// так не работает
                                {

                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: 1) Удалите все лишнее из кода 2) отформатируйте его 3) опишите, что у вас за проблема, как вы сами пытались её решить и что не получилось

Comment: поправил проверите?

Comment: Вас попросили удалить лишнее, отформатировать код и описать текстом (а не комментариями в коде) вашу проблему. Вы же просто добавили еще комментариев в код. Ай ай ай!

Answer (score 1):

Для прояснения вашего вопроса возьмем такой пример суповарения:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var soups = new Recept("Супы", "Фасолевый", "Гороховый");

    var el1 = new Element("сухой горох", 500);
    var el2 = new Element("копченые свиные ребра", 500);
    var el3 = new Element("бекон", 100);
    var el4 = new Element("луковица", 15);
    var el5 = new Element("морковь", 20);
    var el6 = new Element("картофель", 200);
    var el7 = new Element("горчица", 5);
    var el8 = new Element("чеснок", 3);
    var el9 = new Element("укроп и петрушка", 2);
    var el10 = new Element("копченая рулька", 1000);
    var el11 = new Element("охотничьих колбасок", 300);
    var el12 = new Element("сушеной фасоли", 450);
    var el13 = new Element("соль, свежемолотый черный перец", 7);
    var el14 = new Element("лавровый лист", 1);
    var el15 = new Element("розмарин", 0.5);

    soups.AddElements("Фасолевый",
            el10, el11, el12, el5, el4, el8, el13, el4, el15);

    soups.AddElements("Гороховый",
            el1, el2, el3, el4, el5, el6, el7, el8, el9, el14, el13);

    //
    var firstSoup = soups.GetDishesNames().First();
    Console.WriteLine($"Первый суп: {firstSoup}");
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 40));
    foreach (var element in soups.GetElementsByNameDish(firstSoup))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{element.Name} - {element.Weight}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 40));

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Реализовано это с помощью таких классов

```
public class Element
{
    public Element(string name, double weight)
    {
        Name = name;
        Weight = weight;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
}

public class Recept
{
    private Dictionary<string, List<Element>> _dishes;

    public Recept(string name, params string[] dishNames)
    {
        _dishes = new Dictionary<string, List<Element>>(dishNames.Count());
        Array.ForEach(dishNames, d => _dishes.Add(d, new List<Element>()));
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public bool AddElements(string nameDish, params Element[] elements)
    {
        if (!_dishes.ContainsKey(nameDish)) return false;

        Array.ForEach(elements, e => _dishes[nameDish].Add(e));

        return true;
    }

    public List<Element> GetElementsByNameDish(string nameDish)
    {
        if (!_dishes.ContainsKey(nameDish)) return null;

        return _dishes[nameDish];
    }

    public List<string> GetDishesNames()
    {
        return _dishes.Keys.ToList();
    }
}
```

**Теперь глядя на этот пример, исправьте свой вопрос так, чтобы было в достаточной степени ясности понятно какой функционал вам требуется, потому как из вашего вопроса в настоящий момент это не ясно.**